# What is brukta rahita taraka raja yoga

Tags: vedas, krishna, vedic-gods, manuscripts, krishna-yajurveda

I have come to know about it a few days ago. But I’m kinda surprised that we haven’t heard anything about that philosophy in any scriptures. Do any scriptures mention details of shambhala or brukta rahita taraka raja yoga or marjala kishora nyaya

Comment: [It](https://archive.org/details/yogalifeofvissasoutercoverpages4and1_202004/page/n10/mode/1up?view=theater) is the yoga system started by Canchupati Venkatrao Venkaswami Rao (also known as [master C.V.V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_C._V._V.))  in 19th century